# Need clarification about IaaS - Infrastructure as a Service

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, iaas

I am totally new to Cloud Computing. I started learning Cloud computing basics.

I started with Infrastructure as Service and I didnt understand it fully

Please help me with the below questions

1) Does IaaS included the Operating System like (linux or Windows)

2) There are some online article says IaaS includes(network+Storage+servers+Virtualization)

3) In the above 2nd ponint..what is Virtualization..does it mean installing required number of Virtual Machines (VMs) on top of Hypervisor?

4)If the point 3 is true how the VMs are installed without OS

Please help

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to ask such questions. Also looks like you got some reading to do w.r.t cloud. Start here : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/overview/what-is-cloud-computing/

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does IaaS included the Operating System like (linux or Windows)

Infrastructure as a service (IaaS) typically is a cloud offering that grants a user full control over the operating system of a virtual machine (Linux or Windows). There may be some small overlap of traditional adminstrative controls of the VM and services that are provided by the cloud provider; for example, Azure allows you to configure automatic updates on a Windows VM during deployment.

> 2) There are some online article says IaaS includes(network+Storage+servers+Virtualization)

IaaS is a holistic offering of network, storage and compute where the underlying infrastructure is managed by the cloud provider, but the customer interacts with these elements through software. For example, Azure provides access to a VM running on Hyper-V, networking through Software Defined Networking, and storage through virtual disks. These abstractions grant the  customer a high level of control over the resources they purchase without giving them direct hardware level access to the underlying hosting infrastructure.

> 3) In the above 2nd ponint..what is Virtualization..does it mean installing required number of Virtual Machines (VMs) on top of Hypervisor?

Yes, virtualization is the offering of virtual machines on top of a cloud provider managed hypervisor. You will commonly not have access to the hypervisor in most cloud provider platforms.

> 4)If the point 3 is true how the VMs are installed without OS

An OS is required in most IaaS platforms, as this is what you are paying for, rather than a blank virtual machine you configure from scratch. That being said, you can bring you own pre-configured OS disk or deploy from a Marketplace of operating system images. For example, Azure provides many versions of Windows, Ubuntu, CentOS, RHEL, etc. from their own repository that allow you to quickly provision a VM and start building your workload.

Great links:
 - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-iaas/
 - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Shared-Responsibilities-81d0ff91

Comment: If the IaaS includes network+Storage+servers+Virtualization+VMs with Operating System..
Then what is PaaS..there are some online article like below one says IaaS stops just with Virtualization only PaaS provides operating System..
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/understanding-cloud-computing-stack-saas-paas-iaas-big-steven-murhula
Could you please give me some clarity